# How to display two UIImages one over another

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimage

i have to  display two images one below the other. The images should look as if one is overlapping another(more over like a 3d image). i am using(i must use) drawRect method to display the images. i am even putting a code snippet that im using... Ca anyone guide me regarding this. Your inputs would help me go a long way.. Thank you.

*Here coverRect contains an image and UIImage *s is also a image...

```
if (columnIndex == 1) {
            coverRect = CGRectMake(41,77 ,120 ,150 );

            textRect =  CGRectMake(31, 190 ,120 ,15 );
            if (rowIndex != 0 && currentlyInEditingMode == NO) {
                UIImage *s = [UIImage imageNamed:@"tray_center.png"];
                [s drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, s.size.width, s.size.height)];
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the following API,

```
drawInRect:(CGRect)rect blendMode:(CGBlendMode)blendMode alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
```

and for the above image set the alpha value according the opacity value you require. And set the 1.0 as the alpha value for the below image.

Comment: Hi ypk. thanku for your answer..May be i should tell you my qustion a bit more clearly.... The two images are such that one image looks like a book rack and one more image looks like a book. So, i should place a book on the rack in my context... Can you please help me with this...